# Which languange should I start teaching my baby after moving to a new country?

Tags: language-development

I moved from my home country to America and gave birth to my first baby, and one thing bugs me. I want my child to know my languange so she can speak to her family from my side because my family doesn't speak English but I want her to speak English because she lives here, and I don't know with which languange I should start with

- English because she lives here or
- my languange because it's harder and will be more complicated for
  her to learn if she already speaks English?

My languange is pretty hard to learn in general and I always felt English was easy.

Comment: Are you considering daycare for your child? Sometimes it's best to speak your native language at home and let the local language happen in a social environment. This way you're not teaching something you yourself may not be comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

You talk in your language to child and ask your husband to talk in English to child .Then your child will learn both languages.In home you must talk in your language to your husband if he knows your language and he must reply in English.

Comment: she does not specify his language and says "**I** moved.." *implying* that she moved alone. It is not stated if he can speak to her in her own language.

Answer (score 0):

Children learn languages easily.It is unimportant (as long as you are patient) how long your child takes to learn your language, she will learn it just as you did. English is not easy to learn or spell. (I have IELTS 9)

I knew a Swiss family (Switzerland has four national languages) the mother spoke French and the father spoke German. Each parent communicated easily with the other swapping languages all the time. Their children would answer each parent in the parent's preferred language. They could meet any of the four languages in the street or day care.

I would fix upon speaking to your child in your language and let your husband (I assume a US native since you do not specify) use English. She will soon swap easily between the two.